# windows SFC and got a error. need help to understand it

Tags: windows-10

i ran a windows sfc /scannow and got back a log saying Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
here is the link to the log file
https://github.com/echo258/sfc-log/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The files might be in use. Try running `sfc /scannow` from Safe Mode.

Comment: i looked online is the best way to hold down the shift key and click the restart button?

Comment: Refer to this link, and there is some common error you can see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Comment: i think i just want to repair windows with a iso. so to do that i would put it on a usb and i believe there is a repair option that will just fix the image without deleting my personal file. if someone could confirm that for me that would be great. also i know its my registry that has files missing

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - at this point you may want to check for bad sectors or other health issues on the hard drive using [HDDScan](https://hddscan.com). If you find any, it's time to replace the drive.

If you don't, run cmd as administator (search cmd on start menu, right-click and run as administrator), type "chkdsk c: /f /r" without quotes, answer Y and press enter, then reboot your system and let chkdsk do it's thing (may take several hours).

Then run hddscan again and check health and bad sectors. Again, any bad sectors, time to clone and replace hdd.

[Partedmagic](https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/parted_magic,1.html) is a great tool you can use to clone drives.

If drive health is still fine, either re-install using a Win10 boot USB drive (created using the [Win10 update assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)), or run "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" from cmd in Administrator mode.